# Python wrapper for C++ Library

Tags: c++, python, boost, swig

I have .so C++ library (with no source code) and .h header file for it and I want to use this lib in some Python project.

I've googled about it and found out that I can use Boost.Python or SWIG to make a wrapper for C++ lib. But I haven't found example or manual how to deal with already compiled lib with SWIG.

As for Boost.Python I haven't found manual for automatic wrapping all function using header file (found only how to wrap, for example, one function).

I'm looking for an example or links which can help. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

With SWIG wrapping a library with just a header file and a DLL/SO is no different to wrapping any other library with SWIG. In its most basic form you will define an interface:

```
%module my
%{
#include "my.h"
%}

%include "my.h"
```

Then you run SWIG:

```
swig -python my.i
```

And compile

```
gcc -Wall my_wrap.c -shared -o _my.so -lpython -I/path/to/python -lmy
```

There the important thing is that you've linked against the library (`-lmy`) that implements the functions/classes inside your .h file, but you have to do that normally to generate an interface with SWIG.

(If you're using a different compiler you'll need to adapt the above obviously)